# Given a set of positive integers <=k and its n subsets , find union of which pairs of subsets give the original set

Tags: c++, algorithm, set

I have a set A which consists of first p positive integers (1 to p), and I am given n subsets of this set. How can I find how many pair of subsets on union would give the original set A?

Of course this can be done naively by checking the size of the union of each pair and if it is equal to p , the union must make up the set A, but is there a more elegant way of doing this, which reduces the time complexity?

The set_union in c++ has a time complexity of `2*(size(set 1) + size(set 2)) - 1` which is not good for nC2 pairs.

Comment: I am almost sure this is an np problem

Comment: Is there any restrictions on `p`?

Comment: @DAle p can be upto 10^3

Comment: What is this `k` you mention? Did you mean `p`?

Comment: @nakiya ahh sorry edited , yes it is p , thanks :-)

Comment: Ideas for heuristics: min/max elements of each set, density `(max - min)/size` of the sets, number of "holes" per set, ...

Comment: @Angew I don't think it's O(N^2) the maximum size for a subset of a set is  n. For every subset, you must find all elements that are not in it that are in the superset and then for these elements you must compare them against every other given subset and see if they complete it. in other words, in the worst possible case scenario,the last 2 subsets that you checked are the ones that complement each other, you have thus done O(m n n) comparisons, where m is the size of the set.

Comment: @DanielJour Can you elaborate on the holes part?

Comment: First, replace set_union with hand-written cycle from 1 to p that breaks on first integer not containing in any of two sets.

Comment: @DAle Can I  also do this by storing the sets as sorted vectors and then breaking the first smallest number <=p not found in both vectors? will that be of same time complexity?

Comment: @Makogan You're right, it's not n^2. My bad.

Comment: @Ravikishan Sure, you can do this using two pointers (indices). The worst-time complexity wil be the same, but the averege-time complexity could be better.

Comment: @Ravikishan A set with one hole in it together with a set with three holes cannot yield the full set, for example. Reduces the number of pairings to test.

Comment: @DanielJour If I understand holes correctly , if S1 = {1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} has 1 hole (2 not present) and S2={1,2,4,6,8,9,10} has 3 holes , but there union yields the full set

Comment: another approach is usage of `std::bitset`.

Comment: @Ravikishan indeed. Though you can probably use holes as heuristic (learning the likelihood of cases like the one you showed)

Comment: @DanielJour since we need to find all such pairs, I don't think most heuristics would be useful. Knowing if it is unlikely that a pair is a match is not useful if we need to know whether that pair really is a match. `(size1 + size2) < n` "heuristic" (or rather a shortcut) works, although I don't think it can improve the asymptotic worst case complexity.

Comment: @DAle I think this approach is leading to the same time complexity as two loops are used to access the pair of vectors and then another nested loop which would break on first match , It doesn't improve much on the method.

Comment: For clarification: do we need to find all pairs or just the number of pairs?

Comment: @DanielJour Just the no. of pairs

Comment: I figured out how to do it with a reduced time complexity , will post the full solution as soon as I get time , in the meantime if the downvoter of my question sees this comment , pray tell me if the problem was not enough to amuse your intelligence and the reason for your downvote..:-)

Comment: We need to know the nature of your data to give you helpful advice. What real world problem you are trying to solve? What the average sizes or distributions of subsets? Or this is a competitive programming task where you need to optimize worst-case scenario? (I'm not a downvoter :))

Comment: @DAle  Hi DAle , the nature of the problem is itself clear that it's a competitive programming task, where as, I mentioned that the aim is optimization. Anyways much thanks for your efforts , just wanted to say a comment by the downvoter, asking the nature of the problem(or anything related to it) would be more apt instead of blatantly downvoting it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to cope with a worst-case scenario then some ideas about this problem:

1. I suppose that using of `std::bitset` without any optimizations would be sufficient for this task because of the much faster union operation. But if not, don't use variable size vectors, use simple p-length 0-1 arrays/vectors or unordered_sets. I don't think variable size vectors without O(1) find operation would be better in worst-case scenarios.
2. Use heuristics to minimize subsets unions. The simplest heuristic is checking the sizes of subsets. We need only those pairs `(A, B)` of subsets where `size(A) + size(B) >= p`.
3. In addition to heuristics, we can count (in `O(n^2)`) the frequencies of appearing of every number in subsets. After that, we can check the presence of the numbers in some subset(s) in frequence-increasing order. Also, we can exclude those numbers that appear in every subset.
4. If you'll fix some subset `A` (in the outer loop for example) and will find unions with other subsets, you can check only those numbers that do not appear in set `A`. If the subset `A` is large enough this can dramatically reduce the number of operations needed.

Comment: Even I built my algo based on the 4th point you suggested. I fixed a subset in the outer loop and binary searched for 1 to p in both the subsets. Meanwhile kept saving the integers that occured in the fixed subset so that they don't have to be binary searched again if required , I think that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Just a possible improvement to your approach, instead of binary searching you can keep a boolean array to find out if some **x** appears in array **i** in *O(1)*.

For example, 
Let's say, when taking input you save all the appearances for an array **i**. Meaning, if **x** appears in array **i**, then *isThere[i][x]* should be true else false.

This can save some time.

Comment: I get it , you will make a 2D boolean array but then such array has to be saved for every subset , and say I have 10^5 subsets with average length 100 , that wouldn't be viable ,no? This is the reason I am saving only one array for the current outer loop subset.

Comment: bro , forget the max size, take  the avg size of every corresponding boolean array to be 100 (and hence the size of the subsets) , you can have 2^p subsets , hence you need to store in worst case 2^p arrays with length 100...